# Memurai not working with Django app in development with SSL

Tags: python, django, ssl, redis, memurai

I'm building the Django app chat using Memurai. The app is in the development process, but I'm facing an issue. The issue is when I attach the SSL on development my chat not working. How can I configure Memurai with an SSL certificate?

I will appreciate you if you guide me.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Hi Faisal! Can you describe the steps you've taken so far?